# Opencv Installation error

Tags: python, macos, opencv

I installed opencv with home-brew and ran the command `import cv` in python which gave following error.

I am using MAC OS 10.10 .

What is the issue?

```
Jays-MacBook-Air:caffe jay$ brew install opencv
Warning: opencv-2.4.10.1 already installed
Jays-MacBook-Air:caffe jay$ python
Python 2.7.9 |Anaconda 2.1.0 (x86_64)| (default, Dec 15 2014, 10:37:34) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://binstar.org
>>> import cv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named cv
>>>
```

What is the error?

Do I need to set path for opencv?

Thank you:)

Comment: Yes, you should check the `PYTHONPATH` in ~/.bash_profile

Comment: It is export PYTHONPATH=$HOME/work/vislab-git:$PYTHONPATH

Comment: Where should I set it to? I have anaconda python and normal python!

Answer (score 0):

The first step is find where your `cv2.so` is with 
`locate cv2.so`.

The output is  `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so` for my computer.

then, add an additional line

`export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH`

in ~/.bash_profile to let python find the library.